# Codeigniter month links do not work

Tags: codeigniter, hyperlink, calendar

My controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access  allowed');
class Calendar extends MX_Controller
{

 function index()
{

    $this -> display( $year=null, $month=null);

}

function display($year=null,$month=null) 
{   
    if( ! $this->bitauth->logged_in())
    {       
        $this->session->set_userdata('redir', current_url());
        redirect('access/login');
    }
    $data['header']=Modules::run('header/header/index'); 
    $data['footer']=Modules::run('footer/footer/index');

    $conf=array(

        'start_day'=>'monday',
        'day_type'=> 'long',
        'show_next_prev'=>true,
        'next_prev_url'=>'http://datacentral.demo/calendar/'

        );

    $this->load->library('calendar',$conf);

    $this->load->view('calendar',$data);


}
}
```

My views

```
 <?php echo $this->calendar->generate($this->uri->segment(3),   $this->uri->segment(4)); ?>
```

When I change the month, the url looks normal eg. http://example.com/calendar/2017/06 but I keep getting this 404 error not found page.

No route specified in my config file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to create a route liek below:

```
$route['calendar/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'calendar/display';
```

Comment: It's a beginning, the error was gone, but now when I click the links the months don't change :P There's something going one with the route then I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

Try this route link:

```
$route['calendar/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'calendar/display/$1/$2';
```

Comment: The same. Doesn't change the months. This is the url on the top when I go to next month: http://example/calendar/2017/06

Comment: Update: This code echo $this->calendar->generate($year,$month) works on the Controller. How do I pass the variables $year,$month to my view?

Comment: assign `$data['year'] = $year;` and `$data['year'] = $year;`. Then echo `$year` and `$month` in the view.